# Confused about Google Cloud SQL storage usage chart

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Here's a screen cap of my GC SQL Storage usage overview chart:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Why is the storage amount increasing at such a steady rate, and why is it dropping at almost (but not exactly) regular intervals once it reaches between 1.42 and 1.43 GB?

There's no reason I can see that my app would be collecting data at such a consistent rate. And, what's triggering the storage usage drop? Daily backups shouldn't account for this. I can't figure it out. Any useful clues are much appreciated.

Comment: Does it coincide with your backup window? If so, this is due to purging of binary logs.

Comment: It creates daily backups and keeps the for a week before deleting which doesn't coincide with this pattern of about 2.5 to 3 days. My app currently is only reading from the database, no writes. The storage usage is rising in a very linear fashion and dropping at approximately the same heights.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with Binary Logging? I'm not clear on what Binary Logging actually does. The GC documentation doesn't make it very clear to me.

Comment: If you are not performing any writes then the binary log should not grow. Are you performing any large queries that select a lot of data and performing a lot of sorting/grouping? If your query/schema is not setup well, MySQL may perform operations like sorting by writing temporary files to disk.

Comment: I have a couple of queries that join several tables (like 4 or 5)  and select a lot of fields (maybe 35 or 40), but they aren't particularly complex. Also, I'm the only one using it while I'm developing out the basic structure. I'm only generating a small handful of requests per day.

Comment: Can anyone explain how the binary logging works? Is there any way it would be generating small regular amounts of data and subsequently truncating it when it reaches a certain size?

Comment: You can learn more about the binary log in MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html